# preg_replace <table width=""

Tags: html, regex, preg-replace

Not sure why the code below isn't working. Any ideas?

`<table width="567"`

`$text = preg_replace('/<table width=["\']\s*\d+\s*(px|%)\s*["\']/', '<table width="100%"', $text);`

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Use a proper parser instead.

Comment: I see you're using PHP. [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) is pretty nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this pattern :

```
/<table ([^>]*?)width=["\']\s?\d+\s?(px|%)?\s*["\']/
```

The replacement `$1` would preserve any other attributes (cf. `(.*?)` capture group) :

```
$text = preg_replace('/<table (.*?)width=["\']\s?\d+\s?(px|%)?\s*["\']/', '<table $1width="100%"', $text);
```

Comment: Won't work if input string is `<table id="foo" width="42%">`

Comment: Yep, regex won't work anyway in this case. I think the OP would just a quick answer to his actual question and need to dig around by himself for the why's.

Comment: @ EricLavault it's working, thank you.

Comment: @Cid how would you make it work if there WAS a class or an id between table and width?

Comment: @Alex333 using a proper HTML parser, as I mentionned in the comments of your question. Check the first duplicate link

Comment: @Cid I edited my answer so that any other attributes are preserved.

Comment: @EricLavault sorry, but `<table id="foo"><tr><td width="20%">42</td></tr></table>` will fail. You can't *perfectly* parse HTML with RegEx.

Comment: Don't be sorry we know this in the first place, not to repeat myself but in this case : *regex won't work anyway* for parsing self-contained tags, so why arguing ? Just close the question. OR, give an *imperfect* answer with a working solution, at least for the OP original and simple use case, as limited as it is, because the OP *actually asked* how to perform a simple HTML replacement using preg_replace(), you know. Saying *You can't perfectly parse HTML with RegEx* is very nice, though it doesn't answer the question nor suggest any concrete alternative and sounds like a duplicate. But nice.

Comment: @EricLavault by *you can't* I meant *one can't*, you know, french litteral translations